# How to detect when a user has scrolled to the bottom of a div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are a few people who have already asked this question but the last one I can see is almost 10 years old and the code that was given in the answer doesn't seem to work or at the very least doesn't work every time so I thought I would write this as it seems like the code is outdated.

Anyway, I have a div with the id terms, the overflow is set to auto so it is scrollable. I want a hidden div to become visible when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the terms div. At the moment I'm using this

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#terms').on('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            alert('end reached');
        }
    })
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Try replacing the `$(this).innerHeight()` with `$(this).height()`. If you have an overflow element, the actual height of the element will be smaller than the innerHeight because the scroll bar adds an extra padding to the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Elham linking me to this page https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/10827 the page had a negative value on it's if statement I added -100 to my if statement and that gave the event a bit of padding and it works every time.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#terms').bind('scroll', function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight - 100) {
                alert('end')
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well for me.
You can test this code too. I hope this help you:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#terms').bind('scroll', function () {
          if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                    alert('end reached');
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: That seems to work a bit more frequently but when my browser is full screen it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I think this page can help you:https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-check-if-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom-of-the-page.html

Comment: Thanks a million I added the negative value at the end my if statement and that fixed it I'll make a comment with my solution

Comment: I am so happy for you my friend .